# Assigning an element of string to a local variable vs. repeated dereferencing when looping over string?

Tags: c++, string, compiler-optimization

I saw in another post that for a loop such as

```
while(i < n) {
  int val = 4;
  //do stuff
}
```

is equivalent (efficiency-wise) to

```
int val = 4;
while(i < n) {
  //do stuff
}
```

after compiler optimizations and the compiler makes sure that we're not repeatedly creating and destroying the `val` variable on each loop iteration.

Now what if we're looping over a `std::string s`

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
{
  if(s[i] == something) 
  {
    \\ do something
  }
  else if(s[i] == something else) 
  {
    \\ do something else
  }
  //there may be other conditionals
}
```

Would it be better to do something like this following so that we're not repeatedly dereferencing `s`, or does the compiler also optimize the above scenario so that only 1 dereference is performed per loop iteration?

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
{
  auto c = s[i];
  if(c == something) 
  {
    \\ do something
  }
  else if(c == something else) 
  {
    \\ do something else
  }
  //there may be other conditionals
}
```

Comment: You can check it on godbolt (the site, not the person :-) ) try to play with optimization flags.

Comment: Just use a `range-for` loop, then you don't have to worry about it.